# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet not selecting values, and showing: Top Sheet! E102 -> Top Sheet! E15 -> Table7 cannot be located for structured reference

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I am using phpoffice\Phpspreadsheet and when I upload Excel it shows me error
**Top Sheet!E102 -> Top Sheet!E15 -> Table Table7 for Structured Reference cannot be located**

My code is:

```
$file = $request->file;

$readerExtension = ucfirst($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($readerExtension);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($request->file('file'));
$allSheetsArray = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();

$import = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Top Sheet');
$cell = $import->getCell('E102');
$cellDataType = $cell->getDataType();
//$colValue = $import->getCell('E102')->getCalculatedValue();
dd($cell);
```

But when we dump data it shows the result in calculated value. Can anyone please help me with this issue? I have tried many methods to solve this problem but no luck.

[image]

Excel file

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the full error that is output. Also what version of PHPSpreadsheet are you using? Also does the error happen if you do `$colValue = $cell->getCalculatedValue()`?

Comment: I am using: **"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.24"**

production.ERROR: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception: Table Table7 for Structured Reference cannot be located in D:\Work\www\excelImport\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Engine\Operands\StructuredReference.php:150

Comment: @JacobMulquin When we use **$colValue = $cell->getCalculatedValue()**
it will show the same error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Friedrich, Ok I'll take care next time. Thanks for guiding me.

Comment: You can always [edit] to make your question more valuable to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

when we use

```
$colValue = $import->getCell('E102')->getOldCalculatedValue();
```

its working fine.